# How to use ng-hide/ng-show animations

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations

How can I set an animation on an element in Angular when the item's visibility is toggled with ng-hide/ng-show?

What CSS classes do I need to add in order to properly animate elements?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to show / hide elements by changing the effective `display` CSS property. This property cannot be animated (using `transition`). What you can do is changing the `opacity` property, but that has a different behaviour. Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you have added `ngAnimate` as a [dependency to your app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). There are only CSS properties for adding/removing an `ng-hide`, so just reverse your logic if you're doing it for an `ng-show`. `.ng-hide-add` will be triggered when the element is hidden, and vice versa for `.ng-hide-remove`. Add an `animation` CSS property to each class and use your animation of choice.

Remember to chain the CSS properties i.e. classes are directly after one another, not separated by a space.

e.g. use  -> `.box.ng-hide-add` not -> `.box .ng-hide-add`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alanqthomas/Lyroe630/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Inject ['ngAnimate'] in your module.

```
angular.module('animateApp', ['ngAnimate'])
```

I created a sample code:-

http://plnkr.co/edit/QU7VpzBLzjgHd8aqFqv7?p=preview

hope this will help.